# if it's defined as a member function inside a c++ class, I got "non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member"

Tags: c++, syntax, compilation

If I defined sfun() as a member function inside a class, I got the compile error message: "non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member" at the line of "sort(intervals.begin(), intervals.end(), sfun);"

However, if I put it outside of the class, it's fine. Why?

```
struct Interval {
    int start;
    int end;
    Interval() : start(0), end(0) {}
    Interval(int s, int e) : start(s), end(e) {}
};

class Solution {
    bool sfun(const Interval &a, const Interval &b) {
        return a.start < b.start;
    }

    public:   

    vector<Interval> merge(vector<Interval>& intervals) {

        sort(intervals.begin(), intervals.end(), sfun);
    ....
    }
};
```

Comment: Change `bool sfun` to `static bool sfun`, so it won't be a member function instead it will be a class function.

Comment: If it's inside the class you need to refer to it as `&Solution::sfun`, but this will only work if you make it static in your example.

Comment: @Eljay -- terminology: it's still a **member function**, but more completely it's a **static member function**.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `struct` with your comparator inside the class https://ideone.com/AMcMyi

Comment: is there any way I can still define sfun as a non-static function inside the class (a member function) but still able to use it with the sort? If it's just a matter of signature match, the compiler should allow us to do that, right? If so, that's the syntax?  If not, what's the point of preventing us from using it that way?

Comment: @Ben what is wrong with the `struct` approach? You can call `sfun` as a comparator, you can call it like a normal method within the class or if you move it to `public:` you could call it like a public method

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> class Solution {
>     bool sfun(const Interval &a, const Interval &b) {
>         return a.start < b.start;
>     }
> ```

`sfun` is a member function. You can access the implicit `this` pointer inside of it. So you can roughly view it as a function with the signature `bool sfun(Solution* this, const Interval& a, const Interval& b)`.

It works when you put `sfun` outside of the class because then it's not a member function, but a regular free function. It's signature would then be `bool sfun(const Interval &a, const Interval &b)`

You can also make `sfun` a `static` function:

```
class Solution {
    static bool sfun(const Interval &a, const Interval &b) {
        return a.start < b.start;
    }
```

`static` member functions are "class functions." They don't work on instances of a class. There is no implicit `this` pointer. It would just be a regular function.